# Hover horizontal scrolling menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a drop-down menu where a list of items are horizontally shown across the screen. Moving the mouse over the items scrolls the outer items into view.

I have made a simple jQuery function which updates the position of elements in the list.

```
$('.menu').mousemove(function(e){
    $(this).find('li').css('transform','translateX(-'+ e.pageX + 'px)');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLmufy4h/

The only problem is that the cursor **pushes the items too far over** with the cursor near the end.

Comment: Just replace `e.pageX` with `e.pageX/2`. Or even `e.pageX/3`, if you prefer. If you're serious about coding, you'll need to brush up your math a bit. Coding and math go hand in hand, most times. And, btw, if you really *"made"* that function, you'd have known how to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

**Success!** I have finished this hover menu.

I have modified this function to take the width of the menu items into consideration. It calculates a ratio between the page and menu and figures out how much to move the items depending on the location of the cursor.

```
$('.menu').mousemove(function(e){

    // Find the width of all menu elements
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
        totalWidth += parseInt( $(this).outerWidth(), 10 );
    });

    // Find the cursor ratio and position the menu
    var l = (window.innerWidth - totalWidth) * e.pageX / (window.innerWidth-20);
    $(this).find('li').css('transform','translateX('+ l + 'px)');

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLmufy4h/2/

The only thing left is to integrate Hammer.js touch library :)

```js
// Trigger mousemove
$('.menu').mousemove(function(e) {

  // Find the width of all menu elements
  var totalWidth = 0;
  $(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
    totalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(), 10);
  });

  var l = (window.innerWidth - totalWidth) * e.pageX / (window.innerWidth - 20); // Small adjustment for body margin / padding

  $(this).find('li').css('transform', 'translateX(' + l + 'px)');

});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu {
  width: 1000%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 100ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li>DOTA 2</li>
    <li>Heros Of The Storm</li>
    <li>SKYRIM</li>
    <li>Grand Theft Auto 5</li>
    <li>Halo 4</li>
    <li>World of Warcraft</li>
    <li>Counter-Strike: Go</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Man, your awesome, thanks for give your result to your question, i exactly want this thing only, i have searched lot, i really appreciate your effort, once again thank you man...